# How do I convert a multi-table excel spreadsheet with row-wise headers into a tidy data format using R?

Tags: r, pivot-table

I have an Excel spreadsheet with multiple tables on the same sheet, and I'm trying to pivot it into a tidy data format.

These tables have row-wise headers instead of the traditional column headers. All tables have the same set of headers (Name, Date, Dead, Alive, Censored, Comments) and are separated by an empty line.

The actual dataset has many more rows and columns, but here's a sample dataset for now:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Control_1 |  |  |
| Date | 01/01/2023 | 02/01/2023 | 03/01/2023 |
| Dead | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Alive | 10 | 9 | 8 |
| Censored | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Comments |  |  | Some comments here. |
|  |  |  |  |
| Name | Control_2 |  |  |
| Date | 01/01/2023 | 02/01/2023 | 03/01/2023 |
| Dead | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Alive | 10 | 9 | 7 |
| Censored | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| Comments |  |  |  |

The final format that I require:

| name | date | dead | alive | censored | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Control_1 | 01/01/2023 | 0 | 10 | 0 |  |
| Control_1 | 02/01/2023 | 1 | 9 | 0 |  |
| Control_1 | 03/01/2023 | 0 | 8 | 1 | Some comments here. |
| Control_2 | 01/01/2023 | 0 | 10 | 0 |  |
| Control_2 | 02/01/2023 | 1 | 9 | 0 |  |
| Control_2 | 03/01/2023 | 0 | 7 | 2 |  |

Intuitively, I know that this is a pivoting problem - use the dates as headers and then pivot_longer. However, I can't figure out how to split this sheet into multiple tables and then apply pivot_longer to each one. A tidyverse solution would be ideal, if possible.

The spreadsheet has many tables, so manually copy-pasting and then pivoting them in Excel is not an option. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do the contextual headers (i.e. rows with Name and Control_# title) have a recurrent format? I.e. Bold font, different color, or any other consistent pattern?

Comment: Yes, they have the same format - none of them are bold. Edited the example in the question for better clarity

Comment: If the contextual headers have distinct and regular formatting, `tidyxl` can append those formatting values to a tidy df of the workbook cells and thus make it very easy to unpivot them with `unpivotr`.

Answer (score 1):

Some of this will depend on the specifics of the excel file, but I think this will get you started.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

raw_data <- read_excel("Documents/tmp_file.xlsx",
  # skip = 1,                                       # skips first row - use if the first "Name" isn't in row 1
  col_names = c("field", paste0("col_", 1:3)),      # replace "3" with the max columns in the data set or higher.  I'm not sure how to get this to fill in automatically.  
  col_types = 'text'
)

raw_data |>
  mutate(
    name = ifelse(field == "Name", col_1, NA) # pull out "Name" into its own column
  ) |>
  drop_na(field) |> # get rid of the blank rows
  fill(name) |>   # replace NAs with the last value of "name"  
  filter(field != "Name") |> # since name is its own column, don't need those rows anymore
  pivot_wider( # pivot step 1 = create a wide-format version with all the data for each value of "name"
    names_from = field,
    values_from = starts_with("col")
  ) |>
  pivot_longer( # pivot step 2: switch to a "long" format with columns for Date, Dead, Alive, and Censored
    cols = starts_with("col"),
    names_to = ".value",
    names_pattern = "col_\\d+_(.*)"
  ) |>
  mutate( # fix formats
    across(c(Dead, Alive, Censored), as.numeric),
    Date = as.Date(as.numeric(Date),
       origin = "1970-01-01" # adjust if the dates don't translate correctly. (since my dates were created in something other than Excel, I needed to use this on my computer - you probably will not)
    )
  )
```

there is probably a simpler way of doing this, but this should work.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `tidyxl`, `unpivotr`, and `dply` you could try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyxl)
library(unpivotr)

tidy_raw <- #Loads the Excel workbook in a tidy format, each cell as a row.
  tidyxl::xlsx_cells(path = "multi_table_example.xlsx", sheets = 1, include_blank_cells = FALSE)


tidy_raw |> 
  # select(-c(address, sheet, is_blank, character_formatted, formula:local_format_id, error, logical)) |> 
  # uncomment the previous line ito help you visually follow each step in the pipe
  behead(direction = "left", name = "metric") |>
  mutate(text_content = if_else(is.na(character), true = content, false = character)) |> 
  behead_if(data_type == "character" & grepl(pattern = "Control_\\d", x = character), direction = "left-up", name =  "name") |> 
  behead_if(data_type == "date" & metric == "Date", direction = "left-up", name =  "date_header") |> 
  select(col, metric:date_header) |> 
  filter(metric != "Date") |> 
  mutate(metric = tolower(metric)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = metric, values_from = text_content) |> 
  mutate(across(.cols = c(dead:censored), .fns = as.integer),
         date_header = as.Date(date_header)) |>
  rename(date = date_header)

# A tibble: 6 x 7
    col name      date        dead alive censored comments           
  <int> <chr>     <date>     <int> <int>    <int> <chr>              
1     2 Control_1 2023-01-01     0    10        0 NA                 
2     3 Control_1 2023-01-01     1     9        0 NA                 
3     4 Control_1 2023-01-01     0     8        1 Some comments here.
4     2 Control_2 2023-01-01     0    10        0 NA                 
5     3 Control_2 2023-01-01     1     9        0 NA                 
6     4 Control_2 2023-01-01     0     7        2 NA
```